# How to get string representation of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, console

Is there any way to get easily string representation of node without its content? I mean - `element.outerHTML` returns string representation of element AND its content. I'd like to get something like `element.outerHTML` without `element.innerHTML`.

I want to make fallback of dirxml for consoles without support, using `console.group` and `console.groupEnd`

Comment: Can you take the output from outerHTML and then replace innerHTML as blank? It may be a huge amount of code but I think that should work.

Comment: I'm more concerned on performance than on amount of code and it'd be actually few lines of code with regex, or maybe even single line.

Comment: "<"+element.outerHTML.split(/[<>]/)[1]+">"

Comment: actually if you want top speed, avoid the RegExp and make it simpler by using element.outerHTML.split(">",2)[0]+">";

Comment: @dandavis Shorter code is not necessarily faster code. Serializing a big document tree, then stripping parts of the string sounds does not really sound very efficient. And if it does not always work, then it is also useless. An example where you method produces wrong results is `<input value="<" id="something" class="et cetera">`.

Comment: yeah but I actually tested it on my document and getting <body> tag by splitting innerHTML was about 2-3 times faster than cloning nodes. You can read about JS engines performance String.prototype.split is one of fastest possible operations on strings according to O'Reilly "High performance Javascript" and RegExp not

Comment: @user2111737 I'm not arguing that `split` is slower than `RegExp` (`split` is usually faster than a regex), but that serialization of DOM is expensive. When I serialize and split the [W3 document that I'm currently reading in Chrome](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/) using the method from dandavis, then slightly over 5000ns is used. If I use the method from the accepted answer, the method completes in 70 ns.

Comment: is making it complicated worth it to save 4 milliseconds on a worst-case run-once operation?  my posted code also seems to work fine on the example input you provided, making it "not useless"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.cloneNode(false).outerHTML
```

`.cloneNode(false)` creates a duplicate node with identical attributes, but not the child nodes, and `.outerHTML` returns its serialization that matches the original node excluding the node's content.

Comment: it'd be slower than element.outerHTML.replace(element.innerHTML.trim(),'') wouldn't it?

Comment: @user2111737 I guess not. Cloning an element, then serializing it would probably be way more efficient than traversing a whole tree to serialize its content followed by a search-and-replace. Your proposed method would not be reliable either, e.g. consider `<body>body</body>`. Your method returns `<>body</body>`. If you really care a lot about performance, put up test cases on http://jsperf.com